# Can we send messages between two clients using different protocols(STOMP - TCP) with ActiveMQ?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a scenario , where i have my sender code written in Node.js which uses STOMP protocol to publish it to the destination(queue) and the receiver code written in java which use TCP protocol to receive the message from the destination(queue) through ActiveMQ server.Will it be possible for the clients(sender/receiver) to communicate? or it should be the same protocol at either end?

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveMQ documentation covers this on the Stomp page (http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) in the paragraphs

- Working with JMS Text/Bytes Messages and Stomp
- Message transformations
- Stomp extensions for JMS message semantics
- ActiveMQ extensions to Stomp

ActiveMQ supports richt message conversion between messages from different protocols. Not all multi-protocol have this feature, for example ActiveMQ Apollo ([issue 267](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/APLO-267)).

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue. ActiveMQ acts as a multiprotocol message exchange so messages received by the broker in any supported protocol can in turn be sent to receivers in any other supported protocol.